# Is there a better way to do cross-process queues without an external program than this?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code in a function:

```
num_procs.times do

  pid = fork
  unless pid
    DRb.start_service
    ts = Rinda::TupleSpaceProxy.new(DRbObject.new_with_uri('druby://localhost:53421'))

    loop do
      item = ts.take([:enum, nil, nil])

      # our termination tuple
      break if item == [:enum, -1, nil]
      result =
        begin
          block.call(item[2])
        rescue Object => e
          e
        end

      # return result
      ts.write([:result, item[1], result])

    end
    DRb.stop_service
    exit!
  end

  pids << pid
end

pts = Rinda::TupleSpace.new
# write termination tuples
items.size.times do
  pts.write([:enum, -1, nil])
end

items.each_with_index { |item, index|
  pts.write([:enum, index, item])
}

DRb.start_service('druby://localhost:53421', pts)

# Grab results
items.size.times do
  result_tuples << pts.take([:result, nil, nil])
end

pp "Waiting for pids: #{pids.inspect}" if FORKIFY_DEBUG
pids.each { |p| Process.waitpid(p)  }

DRb.stop_service

# gather results and sort them
result_tuples.map { |t|
  results[t[1]] = t[2]
}

return results
```

This code forks a various number of times, the children then attempt to get tuples from the parent using a Rinda::TupleSpaceProxy over DRb. The parent pushes items for each process to call a block on. The children then return their results with different tuples to the parent, which aggregates them.

This code is in a library, so I don't want the user to have to start something like beanstalkd or equivalent just to queue jobs for the process pool. My question is this:

Is there a better way I can be doing cross-process queue communication?

Answer (score 0):

(I tried to run the above code, but even after a few tweaks and requires, I wasn't able to get it going, so take this advice with grain of salt.)

Instead of DRb, it'd probably be better to settle on a beanstalk/delayed_job/[other queue] dependency. If this is just a background job, I'd recommend dj, since it's well-known and easy to start with (see [this example](http://github.com/bmizerany/sinatra-dj) for a quick primer). If you could post more code, it'd be easier to help though.

Comment: I'm sorry, the code above is a snippet from the library, it doesn't run without the other code. The full code for the library is here: http://github.com/dakrone/forkify (you can see the docs and examples there also)

I really wanted to avoid having an external dependency for this library, so hopefully I can find a way without beanstalk or dj.